# How to simulate an LM35 temperature sensor in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, sensors, temperature

I'm trying to simulate an LM35 temperature sensor in Simulink, yet, I couldn't figure out what block components should I use and how to configure each one of them.

My objectives are to:

1. Simulate an LM35 temperature sensor
2. Collect temperature readings from the simulated sensor for a period of time
3. Store the data to perform ML on it later.

Ps: I don't have an LM35 physical sensor, that's why I'm looking to simulate it using Simulink.

Comment: What level of fidelity are you looking for? You could just simulate it with a constant block (fixed temperature) and a random noise block to add some noise on to the temperature signal. However, if you are looking to perform machine learning on it, maybe random data isn't suitable.